# Python 3.4 - Struggling with a basic program that outputs x if a number from 0-9 is typed

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, operator-keyword, algebra

This is just example code for a larger program I'm making, but I can't seem to get it to work. Basically, Python recognises the <= as incorrect syntax, but I'm failing to see how. What is the correct way to write this line on the program?

```
number1 = int(input())

if number1 >= 0 and <= 9:
    print("x")
else:
    print("y")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
if  0 <= number1 <= 9:
    print("x")
else:
    print("y")
```

Answer (score 1):

Make each logic test separately:

```
if number1 >= 0 and number <= 9:
```

or (better) Python supports mathematical-style inequalities:

```
if 0 <= number1 <= 9:
```